# paragraph resizing based on sidebar

Tags: html, css

Ive been trying to figure this out for a while so sorry if I sound weird.

I have a site with a div acting as a header at top. a sidebar at the left side with a button in the header that on click removes the sidebar ( it slides away to the left).

I also have a paragraph that sits under the header and it says home. it has full width currently and it is under the sidebar.

I want to make it so that when the sidebar is open, the paragraph is sized accordingly so it touches the right edge of the screen but touches the sidebar on left and when the sidebar is closed it goes to full width. The whole time I want the text left aligned.

I tried a bunch of things but I can't figure it out
here is some of the code

```css
.sidenav {   
margin-top: 56px;   
width: 280px;   
height: 969px;   
position: fixed;   
top: 0;   
left: 0;   
margin-right: 0px;   
font-family: Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;   
display: block;  
overflow-y: auto;   
overflow-x: hidden;   
flex: 1; 
} 
.sidenav.closed {   
transform: translateX(0px);   
transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out; 
} 
.sidenav.open {   
transform: translateX(-280px);    
transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out; 
} 
container {  
background-color: #92c83e;   
width: 100%;   
padding: 28px;   
margin-top: -8px;   
float: right;   
margin-left: -8px;   
margin-right: -8px; 
} 
.content { /*this is the parapgraph*/
background-color: #b32323; 
text-align: 
left;margin-right: -8px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
height: 54px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }
```

```html
<container id="header contents"\>
<button class="menu-btn" aria-label="Menu" title="Menu" aria-expanded="false" onclick="toggleSidebar()"\>
</button\>
</container\>
 <p class="content">Home</p>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <button class="b1" onclick="window.location.href=('B.Services.html')">Home</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

I tried some javascript thing chatgpt recommended but it didn't work. also tried something like
.content-open {
then width calc(100% - 280px)
280 is the width of the sidebar.
any help is appreciated

Comment: Please format your code (and your question) properly.

Comment: sorry, I think I fixed it.

Comment: this doesn't look like all your code

Comment: I only added what I thought was necessary. My code has lots of un necessary things because I have been trying multiple things.